# how to navigate to an state of an mxmlcomponent-A on clicking a button of mxmlcomponent-B?

Tags: flex3

I have requirement as below
 I want to navigate to a state of an mxmlcomponent (lets assume A) when I click on the mxmlComponentB's button.

how can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways this could be done. Given what context you've given, you could have component A listen to click event on component B's button, and the event handler could change state.

This is a pretty tightly coupled solution, though likely the most straight forward, so it depends on what else is going on with your app.